# Max latencies when working with memory-mapped files

Tags: c++, performance, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

What are the characteristics of worst-case latencies for operations involving memory-mapped files?

I have a high-performance server which is doing logging by writing to a memory-mapped file. Currently the writing to the memory-mapped file location is occurring on the same thread.

In the general case, this should be fast because I am writing to user-space memory but would I incur some bad max latencies if I cross page boundaries?

If bad worst-case latencies were present, I think I would have to copy my log data to another data structure and have another thread do the actual writing to the memory-mapped file. I would make the general case worse though by adding a copy.

Comment: You forgot to mention the operating system.  Generally, no, you'll get the exact same page faults you get when you write to memory that's backed by the paging file.

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.